# Цвета view-элементов поменялись

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно из скрина, цвет у элементов не такой, какой я настроил в программе.

**Как это исправить?**

Comment: Скорее всего дело или в стилях или в отладочных атрибутах превью. Ничего больше по картинкам и скупому описанию проблемы сказать не получится.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб код из каких файлов мне следует прикрепить к вопросу?

Comment: Как минимум разметку, стили.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб пока смотрел разметку, всё встало на свои места, спасибо за участие в решении :)